# How to compile for Android 2.3 with Delphi XE7

Tags: android, delphi, android-ndk, firemonkey

Delphi XE7 comes with FireMonkey for creating Android Apps. After I tryed some codes, I created an APK and tested with My Note2. Works fine. But when I tested with an Android 2.3 samsung phone I couldn't. The excuse is that this version is not supported? I undertand that I need to install API10 in my SDK Manager. But what about the NDK. Where should I download the correct version of this tool to compile to Android 2.3?

Comment: Does the phone satisfies the requirements? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development

Comment: I tryed to compile and there is 2 errors. 1: aapt.exe from build-tools only exists in api19, I can't find it in api10. 2: [PAClient Error] Error: E2312 C:\Users\eduardo.alcantara\Dropbox\ProntoDigital\meupda\Mobile\MeuPDA\Android\Debug\MeuPDA\AndroidManifest.xml:38: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' in package 'android'

Comment: @SirRufo Yes, it is API10

Comment: Read the entire page @SirRufo linked. Besides API requirements, there are **hardware requirements**, including limitations on the processor. When someone provides you information that might be helpful, **actually read all of the information** so you don't waste your (and our) time. The entire page is full of the requirements your device must meet. It's not simply the API.

Comment: @KenWhite Ok, Ken, Thanks for the advice and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Android 2.3 is supported. Some older devices which do not have the NEON instruction set and devices running X86 processors (but no ARM emulation) are not supported.

Comment: @FMXExpress Could you answer with the proper instructions to change XE7 default Android API 19 to compile to API 10?

Comment: Edit the manifest file and add these settings: https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html#minsdkversion

Comment: @FMXExpress Are you talking about AndroidManifes.template.xml from the project? There is a line `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="%minSdkVersion%" android:targetSdkVersion="%targetSdkVersion%" />` so should those configurations be made inside delphi options pane? I can't find them. So, if there is % symbol, it means that Delphi handles it. May I change it manually safely?

Comment: You can probably edit it but I checked the outputted manifest file and it already outputs to this: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="11" /> so it should already be good to go.

Comment: As has been mentioned, any old Delphi Android app should run on Android 2.3 upwards on a suitable device. No tweaking is required.
I'm not sure you have stated the actual problem clearly. What exactly is it that says some version is not supported? What is the exact text of the message?
And how does that error message relate to your other cited issue of a PAClient error?

Comment: The PAClient error relating to hardwareAccelerated sounds like you took a demo app compiled for an an earlier version (maybe XE5 or XE6) and tried to compile it in XE7. You can resolve this issue by deleting the AndroidManifest.template.xml from the project directory and rebuilding. A fresh one should then be generated.
Might be worth backing up the existing one in case there is anything in there you need to migrate over.
Do a Beyond Compare (or similar) on the original and the replacement one to see what changes were given to you and what you may need to restore from what you have.

Answer (score 0):

To find out if your device is supported check out this excerpt from [Brian Long's blog post](http://blog.blong.com/2013/09/delphi-for-android-aka-delphi-xe5-aka.html):

> (From the Android SDK directory) ... run the command:
>
> *adb devices*
>
> just to prove that your device can be seen by the Android tool chain.
>   Assuming it can, run:
>
> *adb -d shell cat /proc/cpuinfo*
>
> Check the Processor line to ensure you are running ARMv7. In the
>   Features line check that NEON is included in the CPU feature list